# Download and Install Microsoft R Client version greater than 4

Tags: r, visual-studio, installation, microsoft-r

I have Microsoft R client 3.5.2 to use in Visual studio 2017. However, some of the packages are not working with this version.

I want to install Microsoft R client version greater than 4 or the latest version. I am not able to find any link /URL regarding that. I want to this R client in visual studio.

Comment: If you really want Microsoft's version of R, you can download it from https://mran.microsoft.com/ That version is somewhat behind, but it should be already 4.x

Comment: Have you tried tpetzoldt's suggestion? And does it work?

Comment: It has R-open greater than version 4. However, that is different from R client version. I have installed R-open 4.0.2. Can you please let me know how let R-client know to use the R-open.